# iPhone SDK: Customizing back button title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In XCode 5. I want to change all back button title is **"Back"** after pushViewController call function. I do not want to add new navigation bar button. Is there available simple code?

Comment: Create your custom back button.

Comment: check my answer... if you want back button with same shape (instead of square button), you can do what I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it. it is simple code below
**FirsViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
                self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
            }
```

Press button call to next view controller
**FirsViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)button{
    SecondViewController *view = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @FahimParkar Did u test it?

Comment: Did you test it? **YES I CHECKED AND ITS SQUARE BUTTON** You want code for the same?

Comment: **EVEN BUTTON WITH `target:nil action:nil` IS USELESS**. ***THERE WILL BE NO EFFECT ON BACK BUTTON CREATED BY YOU***

Comment: when buttonAction will get called?

Comment: @FahimParkar I had put a button into firstViewcontroller and press this button to Secondviewcontroller. u can see back button like (<=) in secondviewcontroller.

Comment: can i see the code where you are adding back button and where you are calling buttonAction??

Comment: @FahimParkar u no need to see the code. must write code in xcode. if u get problem send me simple project.

Comment: @FahimParkar Did u test it?

Answer (score 0):

What @NagRaja is suggested can be done, **but disadvantage is you will have square back button**

If you want Back written on each back button with same design (<=), in all view controller have this.

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"Back";
}
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"Back";
}
```

And in viewWillAppear have

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"Your Title";
}
```

---

### EDIT 1

If you are fine with square button use below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(takeMeBack)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

-(void) takeMeBack {
    NSLog(@"takeMeBack");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

@NagRaja code will not have any effect on backbutton as he have `target:nil action:nil`